# How to angle the Churchill VII to minimize the chance of being damaged?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I've calculated that using the Churchill VII if I angle my tank roughly **32 degrees** relative to my target my effective armor will be something around **179mm** which is very good in a Tier VI match. What I've noticed however is that there is a weak spot in the inner side of both tracks next to the UFP where even a lower tier tank can score a hit relatively easily.

My question is: how should I angle my tank? In order to protect the hole next to the tracks (is this a bug or intentional?) I have to be angled **0 degrees** (no angling) so a tank in front of me can't hit it but in that case I'm not angling at all!

What is the best tactics in case of an **1v1 with another tank** when driving the Churchill VII?

Comment: I've never driven the churchill but if it has decent turning rate you can try wiggling to make that weakpoint harder to hit.

Comment: I was wondering whether front/back or left/right wiggling would help and I think that front/back is better when angled properly. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Should I wiggle my turret as well? It has the same armor layout as the hull. (best when angled at 32 degrees)

Comment: I wouldn't wiggle the turret much as that could possibly screw with *your* aim.

Answer (score 1):

**All tanks have weak spots by design**, otherwise everyone would roll only with that one I suppose :)

**To protect the hole**, you cant do considerably much. Those, who are aware of this weak spot, they will just chase it, and many tanks are faster than Churchill VII. 
 Wiggling from 0° is useful, you can get the enemy to a bit mess up aiming and only to rely on RNG to hit you on weakspot if you care to close-reopen weakspots fast and you can keep focus on him. Left-right is better, because only top end light tanks have that acceleration that would help reasonably to deflect shells relying on extra reverse speed (+7-15 km/h). Forward-reverse wiggle generated unpredictability for aiming has less efficiency by my experience. A cold-blooded foe can easily stay patient to not reload gun because of missed shot. I would suggest aslo to avoid turret wiggling. It has relatively more weakspot area, and majorly decreases your aiming.

**There is no best 1v1 tactic**, all are different and unique to win. Depends on enemy player.